# Are there official names sub parts of a full url?

Tags: http, url, web

I would like to clear up some terminology related to the name of different parts of a web address. 
I'm pretty sure about these

```
+-------------------------+-----------+
|         Example         |   Name    |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| foo.com                 | domain    |
| www                     | subdomain |
| http://                 | protocol  |
| 8000                    | port      |
| http://www.foo.com:8000 | url       |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

However I do not know if these have official names:

```
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|     Description     |      Example       | Name         |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| no protocol or port | www.foo.com        | hostname?    |
| no port             | http://www.foo.com | url?         |
| no protocol         | www.foo.com:443    | ?            |
| domain no extension | foo                | ?            |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: The first one would be "host name".

Comment: The second one is also a "url". It just implies the default port for the protocol.

Comment: What if the port is `8000` and just not specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official name for a full absolute url is actually a URI.

The official name for a relative url is URI Reference.

- `http`   is the scheme
- `foo.com`, `user@foo.com` or `foo.com:80` is called the `authority`. The `authority` is a combination of `host`, `port` and `user`.
- `/foo/bar` is the `path`.
- `?foo=bar` is the `query`
- `#foo` is the `fragment`.

This roughly speaking means:

```
https://user@example.org:80/foo/bar?foo=bar#foo
scheme://user@host:port/path?query#fragement
schema://authority/path?query#fragment
```

Subdomain is, as far as I know not an official term.

Different schemes have different rules though. This is also a uri:

```
mailto:foo@example.org
```

In that case:

1. `mailto:` is the `scheme`.
2. `foo@example.org` is the `path`.
3. There is no authority or host part (despite there being a host name).

References:

- The official RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986
- I wrote a popular URI parser for PHP: https://packagist.org/packages/sabre/uri

Answer (score 2):

Assume we have the below address:

```
https://account.digikala.com:6985/inventory/index.html?q=car&category=9095#top
```

- The whole address name is [**`URI`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/URI), [**1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax), [**2**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)
- The `https://account.digikala.com:6985/inventory/index.html` is [**`URL`**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)
- The `https` part name is [**`Protocol`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/protocol)
- The `https://account.digikala.com:6985` is [**`Origin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/origin)
- The `account.digikala.com:6985` is [**`Host`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/host)
- The `account.digikala.com` is [**`Hostname`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hostname)
- The `account` is [**`Subdomain`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)
- The `digikala.com` is [**`Domain`**](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url), As you see, it has two parts, [*TLD*](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url#domain-name): `digikala` and [*SLD*](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url#domain-name): `.com`
- The `/inventory/index.html` is [**`Pathname`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname)
- The `?q=car&category=9095` is [**`Query`**](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url#query) which called [**`Search`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search) and [**`Parameters`**](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url#parameters) are separated by `&` so in this *URI* we have `q=car` and `category=9095` parameters
- The last part `#top` is [**`Fragment`**](https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url#fragment) which is called [**`Hash`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash)